# How to remove extra <p> & </p> generated by adsense code

Tags: html, css, wordpress, adsense

If you visit this [link](http://www.japaneseemoticons.net/confused-emoticons/) page you will see an extra space above tagline that is just above footer. How can I remove that?
This is the PHP inside which google adsense code is placed.

```
<?php cpotheme_show_taglines('post_bottom', 'tagline_bottom'); ?>
```

Comment: have your tried something to your own??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to remove empty `<p></p>` tags

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```

Or if you are concerned about the space it takes up, you could simply hide it using CSS

```
p:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: why do you loop through every paragraph instead using :empty selector?

Comment: @Pawel_W Am just jQuery beginner, this is what I used for my blog, so I remembered this and I shared

Comment: @Pawel_W it's an answer, not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) to find `<p></p>` in your document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p:empty').remove();
});
```